# What is the cause of "It seems that this project has not been built yet. Do you want to build it now?" message when compiling using Codeblocks?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I recently installed Code::Blocks and GCC for C. When I try to compile a simple hello world program, I get a message saying "It seems that this project has not been built yet. Do you want to build it now?

However, when I click yes the box comes up again, and I can't get out to compile my code. If I click no I get the error message 'Process terminated with status 4258096' Does anyone know what's happening? I don't think its my code causing this but I'll post it anyway.

```
void main (void) {
    printf("hello world");
}
```

Comment: On which operating system? Why don't you compile with `gcc -Wall -g yourcode.c -o yourbinary` on the command line?

Answer (score 3):

`void main() {...}` is **wrong**, and you shouldn't declare your main function this way. It is very out of the date and you if you are compiling with any major compiler then you almost certainly need to be returning an int from main function.

It's not even standard and if you are using any material that says using it is valid, then throw it in the garbage.

According to the standard, there are two valid signatures for main:

```
int main(void) {} // Return type of int with no parameters
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {} // Return type of int with two parameters
```

In C99 and on, `int main()` can be left out without a return statement since by default it's returning 0.

Note: even if your compiler is allowing you to use `void main()`, you should avoid it.

`main() {}` is an error because C99 does not allow you to omit the type of the main function.

Check if `gcc` is installed correctly on your system with `gcc -v`. Compile your file with `gcc -Wall -g filename.c`.

Comment: While it's true that `void main()` should be avoided, it's not clear how this would cause the problem described in the question. At worst, I'd expect this to raise a warning.

Comment: It is bad habit and should be pointed out. It could compile program depending on compiler, but still shouldn't be used nonetheless. For the problem described in his question, I specifically asked does he have properly installed `gcc -v` and to compile program using -Wall option flag to raise any warning messages.

Comment: `void main ()` is only wrong for a conforming implementation, it is 100% valid for a freestanding implementation. *"In a freestanding environment (in which C program execution may take place without any benefit of an operating system), the name and type of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined."* See: [C11 Standard - 5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.1). Compared to [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1).